# What are the benefits of defining a variable on one line and create an instance of it on the next line

Tags: java, android, instance, instantiation

For example consider the slide from the Google I/O '17 "Android Animations Spring to Life":

[image]

```
SpringForce force = new SpringForce(0)
        .setDampingRation(0.4f)
        .setStiffness(500f);
for (int i = 0; i < heads.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View child = heads.getChildAt(i);
    SpringAnimation anim;
    anim = new SpringAnimation(child, DynamicAnimation.ROTATION);
    anim.setSpring(force).setStartValue(-25).start();
}
```

There we can see that variable `anim` is defined on one line and the instance of the variable is created on the next line. Sometimes I also see that approach in some open source projects.

Is there a real benefit of using that approach or it is just a matter of style or readability? Or, in the case of slides, it is a matter of fitting the width of the slide? But if that's so they could have written something like:

```
SpringAnimation anim = new SpringAnimation(
        child, DynamicAnimation.ROTATION);
```

Comment: Please post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Have you taken a look at the generated bytecode? I have a feeling that it is pretty much the same.

Comment: It's just a matter of style and readability (including the slide width aspect -- for instance, I find it much clearer the way they did it than your proposed way). But particularly for slides, as a matter of style, doing one thing per line makes sense.

Comment: Right matter of taste and readability. I for one don't like uninitialized variables around. It interrupts me when skimming over the code popping the question "what's this unitialized variable doing here?" until I find where its initialized. Also I think it may lead to errors if with a bugfix code gets rearanged(you focus at the problem at hand and not the whole thing) and the variable is actually getting used uninitialized. But its matter of taste. As others metioned, long lines don't help readabilty either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's do a little experiment. Given the following two classes:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Integer i = Integer.valueOf(1);
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}

public class Test2 {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Integer i;
    i = Integer.valueOf(1);
    System.out.println(i);
  }
}
```

we can take a look at the generated bytecode:

```
> javac *.java && javap -c *.class
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
  Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
  Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       4: astore_1
       5: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       8: aload_1
       9: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      12: return
}
Compiled from "Test2.java"
public class Test2 {
  public Test2();
  Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
  Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: invokestatic  #2                  // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
       4: astore_1
       5: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       8: aload_1
       9: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
      12: return
}
```

Since the generated bytecode is identical, it is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Altho everyone have a good point on readability and good coding standard, the example provided shows that there are some objects that have mandatory and optional fields.

The code above could easily be put together in the same "line" like this:

```
Obj o = new Obj([mandatory args])
  .optionalParam1(...)
  .optionalParam2(...);
```

But the decided to separate the mandatory from the optional, so its more readable and well organized (or at least thats what I think).

They have proven that it doesn't matter because the code is the same at the end, so it us up to you to decide which practices work for you and which doesn't (I like to heavily comment on my code so is easier to come back, but I only do it in my personal projects because my workteam doesn't find it valuable if the code is clean and self explanatory).

Both answers from @Turing85 and @Kavita_p are good and they provide enough context and information for you!

Comment: Well if  we talk readability and usability, I would prefer to see a fluent builder. This way, we have readable way of expressing how the object is constructed, as well as proper execptions when construction is done wrong or necessary parameters are not set. [DZone has a good example of how builders can improve readability](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern).